# Spring Major version '3' expected, but you are running with version: 2.5.6.SEC01

Tags: spring, weblogic, jdeveloper

I am running into the below error after upgrading JDeveloper from 12.1.0 to 12.1.3. The below link confirms that JDeveloper which ships integrated Weblogic 12.1.3 supports Spring Framework versions 3.0.x, 3.1.x and and 4.0.x. So, I am not using Spring 2.5.6 and Oracle does not ship that version in 12.1.3. Any pointers to troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance.

[Oracle 12 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SPRNG/intro.htm#SPRNG291)

```
<Dec 9, 2014 2:39:23 PM EST> <Error> <org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion> 
<BEA-000000> <*** Spring Major version '3' expected, but you are running with version: 2.5.6.SEC01. 
Please check your classpath for unwanted jar files.> 
<Dec 9, 2014 2:39:23 PM EST> <Warning> <org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion> 
<BEA-000000> <**** You are advised to use Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE or later with this version. You are running: 2.5.6.SEC01> 
<Dec 9, 2014 2:39:23 PM EST> <Error> <org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader> <BEA-000000> <Context 
initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document 
from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1838)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:226)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:418)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:753)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: See this same question here (even though it's an older version of weblogic I believe it is the same problem): http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/119195-spring-3-1-and-weblogic-10-3-5 Try using `prefer-application-packages` You may need to post the contents/structure of your war file

Comment: Adding spring using prefer-application-packages helped.